# Unable to install [npm firebase] in my react app due to peer dependencies error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, web, npm-install

i am trying to install firebase packing using npm install firebase, but i get error thrown at me

```
PS C:\veda> npm install firebase
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @emotion/react@11.11.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0-rc.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0-rc.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.11.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!   peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.11.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.12.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.11.16
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/system, @mui/styled-engine, the root project)
npm ERR!   peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.12.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!     peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.11.16
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!       @mui/icons-material@"^5.11.16" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!   3 more (@mui/system, @mui/styled-engine, the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.11.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.11.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.12.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!         peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.11.16
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/system, @mui/styled-engine, the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.12.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.11.16
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.11.16" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/system, @mui/styled-engine, the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-16T07_10_08_669Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-16T07_10_08_669Z-debug-0.log
```

I am not able to understand why it is not downloading, it is a first for me.
please help.

i have tried using --force and ----legacy-peer-deps but nothing seems to work

do i have to update any dependancies??